# Any way to switch between ul and ol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have issue to dynamically create list(ol or ul). The problem I face is that sometimes I need ordered list and sometimes un-ordered depending upon the JSON. I am using knockout, Here is my html,

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: items" ><li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li></ol>
```

Here is my JSON,

```
{
   items: ['a','b','c'],
   orderedList: true
}
```

You can see that orderedList may be true or false. If true then I need to use ol and if false I need to use ul. I also to avoid replication. Any way to do this.

Comment: use container less bindings to generate the ul/ol tag and also for your for each

Comment: @ryadavilli, any example?

Comment: visually the only difference between a `ul` and `ol` is css `list-style-type`. Can number items in a `ul` also by setting `decimal` so you could bind a class change depending on data

Comment: @charlietfl, The problem is that ul can't be numbered and ol can't be bullet.

Comment: yes they can, it's done with simple css...see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gbUtw/

Comment: @charlietfl, really nice. But I still prefer semantics. ol makes sense for numbers and ul for for un ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a crude sample I put together, was not able to test it. But you can get the idea.

```
<!-- ko if : orderedList -->
<ol>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot : orderedList -->
<ul>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if : orderedList -->
</ol>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot : orderedList -->
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**EDIT:** There is no if-else condition in knockout. So you will have to rely on using multiple Ko if statements.

**EDIT2**: The version of the code that worked for the OP.

```
<!-- ko if : orderedList -->
<ol data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li>
</ol>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot : orderedList -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Your code giving me error no, 'Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if : orderedList'

Comment: At which place? Is it the first usage of the ko if? or the second one ?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I have solved the issue using please edit your answer, <!-- ko if : orderedList --><ol data-bind="foreach: items"><li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li></ol><!-- /ko --><!-- ko ifnot : orderedList --><ul data-bind="foreach: items"><li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li></ul><!-- /ko -->

Comment: Glad to know it worked. At least a variation of it. I was able to remove the error but was still struggling with the code I had given.